# How to parse two list into a dictionary, where the id property in both becomes the key?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I seem to have a hard time figuring out an easy way of inserting my old and new registration into a dictionary formatted like

```
Dictionary<int, List<Registration>, List<Registration>>
```

Where the first list contain oldReg, and the other one contains new registration.
They have an id in commmon, which has to be the key, and if that is not the case, then the shall the other list be empty.

I seem to have a hard time figuring out an Linq statement capable of doing so, I would assume this was a job for GroupBy or GroupJoin, but cannot figure out how it should look like..

MVC: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BIbPqY

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> openWith =
                new Dictionary<string, object>();
        openWith.Add("txt", "notepad.exe");
        openWith.Add("bmp", "paint.exe");
        openWith.Add("dib", "paint.exe");
        openWith.Add("rtf", "wordpad.exe");
        
        Registration reg1 = new Registration()
        {
            id = 1,
            attributes = openWith
        };
    
        Registration reg2 = new Registration()
        {
            id = 2,
            attributes = openWith
        };

        Registration reg3 = new Registration()
        {
            id = 1,
            attributes = openWith
        };
        
        Registration reg4 = new Registration()
        {
            id = 2,
            attributes = openWith
        };
        
        List<Registration> oldReg = new List<Registration>() {reg1, reg2 }; 
        List<Registration> newReg = new List<Registration>() {reg3, reg4 };
        
        Console.WriteLine("Hellow World");
    }
    
    public class Registration
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public Dictionary<string, object> attributes {get; set;}
    }
}
```

My current way of handling is by creating two dictionaries by using groupBy

```
Dictionary<int, List<Registration>> oldRegDic = 
        oldReg.GroupBy(o => o.id).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
Dictionary<int, List<Registration>> newRegDic = 
        newReg.GroupBy(o => o.id).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

        Dictionary<int, (List<Registration>, List<Registration>)> oldAndNewRegistrationDictionary = new();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Registration>> newReg in newRegistrationDictionary)
        {
            (List<EntityRegistration>, List<EntityRegistration>) oldNewPair = new()
            {
                Item1 = oldRegDic[newReg.Key], Item2 = newRegDic[newReg.Key]
            };
        }
```

And then iterate through them both an add them to a new Dictionary, but thats looks very inefficient.

Comment: `Dictionary<int, List<Registration>, List<Registration>>`  doesn't make sense.  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` only takes two generic type parameters.  Maybe you intended to have a class that has both lists?  `class Foo { public List<Registration> list1, list2; }` and then have `Dictionary <int, Foo>` ?

Comment: it was to avoid making an entire class for it, but I see your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to have Full Join here, but it can be emulated by two queries:

```cs
var query1 = 
    from n in newReg
    join o in oldReg on n.id equals o.id into gj
    from o in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { id = n.id, n, o };

var query2 = 
    from o in oldReg
    join n in newReg on o.id equals n.id into gj
    from n in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where n == null
    select new { id = o.id, n, o };

var result = query1.Concat(query2)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => Tuple.Create(x.o, x.n));
```